# Aggregate top 5 categories and rest as others in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

We have a use case where we want to aggregate the top 5 records and the rest should be coming as others. Others will be the aggregation of the rest of the data that is present.

Sql equivalent of the same
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/312cc/6

Comment: Could you please be more specific in your question and add some examples of your data and the expected result of the query?

Comment: @Kaveh Could share the sql equivalent of the same question